# Difference between Oomph and Workspace Mechanic

Tags: java, eclipse, oomph

We're looking for a way to synchronize Eclipse workspaces (and associated settings) at our company. I've already found plenty of related questions on Stack Overflow and the most promising tools seem to be [Oomph](https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/tools.oomph) and [Workspace Mechanic](https://code.google.com/archive/a/eclipselabs.org/p/workspacemechanic). Are there any significant differences between them?

**EDIT:** [My comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38588095/difference-between-oomph-and-workspace-mechanic#comment64688070_38612619) probably should be part of the question as well:

> According to the Google Code Archive, Workspace Mechanic is in maintenance mode, so there'll be critical bug fixes only. Even though Oomph seems to be "the thing" within the Eclipse community, I'm not sure if it fits our needs. We're looking for a way to keep our workspace settings in sync over time, rather than an installer.

Answer (score 2):

Both projects share similar goals. The technical approach and the concepts are not the same.

Oomph is the newest/latest attempt. The adoption is good inside the Eclispe Community (developers building something on top of Eclipse) and the project leaders are really active.

I am not sure if the development of "Workspace Mechanic" continues.

Comment: According to the Google Code Archive, Workspace Mechanic is in maintenance mode, so there'll be critical bug fixes only. Even though Oomph seems to be "the thing" within the Eclipse community, I'm not sure if it fits our needs. We're looking for a way to keep our workspace settings in sync over time, rather than an installer.

Comment: Oomph is not just an installer for IDEs. It also deploys its setup engine into the installed IDEs, so that these IDEs and their workspaces stay in sync with the chosen setup profiles.